# Запуск Java программы из консоли с параметрами CSV и XML

Tags: java

В общем, делаю проект, чтобы пустили на стаж. В проекте требуется запустить программу из командной строки (> compile.bat && run.bat [argumenty]). В самом начале имею CSV и XML документы, написал программу которая парсит csv и xml, но указал явно путь к их положению, а требуется считывать аргументы из консоли, и если честно, не понимаю, что подразумевается под аргументом. В программу будет передаваться адрес нашего xml и csv или же будет целиком оба документа. Прошу подсказать более опытных, если будут передаваться адреса, то в общем все легко и понятно, но если целые файлы, то подскажите, пожалуйста, какую-то статью или примерный путь, как реализовать обработку того же xml после считывания. Спасибо!

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "целые файлы"? Судя по команде, указанной вами в скобках, программа должна принимать в аргументах пути к файлам.

Comment: Это зависит от размера xml файла, можно использовать потоки для загрузки CSV. Просто непонятно что именно вы хотите делать без написания кода.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Спасибо, понял что в консоли мы указываем путь к XML, а не сам файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Речь конечно же идёт об аргументах/параметрах командной строки, вариант с передачей самих файлов в программу - это из области фантастики. Аргументы/параметры командной стоки, это то, что было передано программе после имени файла программы, можно считать в функции `main(String args[])`. args[] - это и есть массив с параметрами.

Подробности смотрите тут [The Java™ Tutorials - Command-Line Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)